# Linear equation without NumPy

Tags: python, math, linear-algebra

I am relatively new to Python and programming in general. At the moment, I am doing Repl.it student courses. The statement/instruction is as follows:

> Write a program that solves a linear equation `ax = b` in integers. Given two integers, `a` and `b`, where `a` may be zero, print a single integer root if it exists and print "no solution" or "many solutions" otherwise.
>
> Example input: `a = 1`, `b = -2`
>
> Example output: `-2`

My code so far looks like this:

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())

if a==0:
  print("many solutions")
elif (b == 0):
  print (b)
elif (a!=0):
  x=int(b/a)
  if x!=0:
     print(x)
  elif x==0:
     print("no solution")
```

It fails when a = 0 and b = 7. I do not know why though. Any answers will be much appreciated.

Edit: Thanks for the answers, they were helpful. I have managed to come up with a solution that worked.

Comment: In what way does it fail? It doesn't return the correct answer, or it returns an error?

Comment: "It fails when a = 0": no it does not. It prints "many solutions".

Comment: Before you start coding, analyse the problem. Break it down into separate cases like (a=0, b=0), (a=0, b!=0), (a !=0, b!=0, b/a is an integer) etc. The coding will then be pretty straightforward afterwards.

Comment: @Tim It does not return the correct answer. It is supposed to be "no solution". I just do not know why exactly which may be why I struggle with this assignment.

Comment: You must have learned a formula to calculate this. Does the code follow that formula?

Comment: I tested your code and it does return "many solutions"

Comment: If `a==0` you are printing `many solutions` because your first conditional tells the program to print that!  And it's incorrect since `a==0` should display `no solution` Also the last `elif a != 0` is redundant

Comment: This is what is known as "divide by zero" error.  Python should tell you that the result is NaN - not a number.  This problem has less to do with programming and more to do with a deficient mathematics background.

Comment: @duffymo You are correct about mathematics background. It has been approximately 12 years since I last had any maths.I have fixed the code so it works now. I don't know the general rules here, whether I should post my edits or not.

Comment: The likelihood of an integer root is small.  Double is better.  If you do integer division you'll get the wrong answer when a < b and doesn't divide evenly. The problem is that concept of "can't divide by zero" is hardly advanced math.  I knew that before I got to high school.  Unless you never went to grammar school you ought to know this, regardless of how long it's been.

Comment: @duffymo. Thanks. I know you can't divide by zero which is why I wrote: a!= 0. Anyways I have fixed it. Forgive me for my ignorance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this to work properly thanks to some of the comments.

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())

if a == 0:
  if b == 0:
    print('many solutions')
  else:
    print('no solution')
elif b % a == 0:
  print(b // a)
else:
  print('no solution')
```